# Show variable in switch statement

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

```
switch (name){
    case "Rusia":
       String a="Tuan Rumah"
        break;
    case "Brazil":
        String a="Zona Concacaf"
        break;
}
zona.setText(a);
```

How to show variable "a" into zona textfield in android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `a` outside of the switch statement, and then set it inside. For example:

```
String a = "";
switch (name){
    case "Rusia":
        a = "Tuan Rumah";
        break;
    case "Brazil":
        a = "Zona Concacaf";
        break;
    default:
        a = "Unknown";
}
zona.setText(a);
```

Comment: Updated my answer. I've initialised `a` to an empty value, which will always be set in the `switch` statement as I prefer to use the `default` case, but you can equally set the default value before the switch statement as per Neng Liu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Define it out the switch block:

```
    String a = "default";
    switch (name){
        case "Rusia":
            a="Tuan Rumah"
            break;
        case "Brazil":
            a="Zona Concacaf"
            break;
    }
    zona.setText(a);
```

Comment: i try, but if i run this code, variabel "a" show is "default" text

Comment: @BonyJoesadi That means your `name` does not equals `Rusia` or `Brazil`

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "";
switch (name){
    case "Rusia":
        a = "Tuan Rumah";
        break;
    case "Brazil":
        a = "Zona Concacaf";
        break;
}
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(a))
    zona.setText(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define variable 'a'  outside of switch statement and before it:

```
String a ="":
Switch()
```